# Renaming the 4th character through the 12th

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Here is what I have.

```
get-childitem "\\myfileserver\out\*" | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_123456_837P.", ".").Replace(".test.", ".sa.").Replace("_987654_837I." , ".") }
```

Here is the filename I want to fix
999_987654_837I.74161.test

I want to remove _987654_837I from the file name. I was just going to rename it but those numbers may change. So now I want to remove the 4th character starting at the _ and back to the "I" or 9th character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex pattern to get the required part.

See regex example + explanation:
https://regex101.com/r/xNoBVD/2

I use positive lookbehind to force regex to get the first 3 characters at the very beginning of the line (^) without capturing it. The following 12 characters are captured and can then be replaced with ''

```
$regexReplacePattern = '(?<=^.{3}).{12}'

'999_987654_837I.74161.test' -replace $regexReplacePattern, ''
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning you don't need to use a rename items inside a foreach loop. `Get-ChildItem "\\myfileserver\out\*" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=^.{3}).{12}', '' }`